# Image shows on home page, but not on article page

Tags: media

I am using [Open Outreach](http://openoutreach.org/). When I create an article the image I uploaded appears on the home page, but does not appear when I click the link for that article.

From what I've read, it looks like it has something to do with Configuration/Media/File System. My public file system path is set as sites/openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd/files. Do I need to change this? If so, what do I change it to?

Log message:

Type    page not found
Date    Thursday, June 4, 2015 - 9:43am
User    admin
Location    http://openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd:8083/sites/openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd/files/styles/medium_large/public/Portulaca%20grandiflora.jpg?itok=OP-6w24x
Referrer    http://openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd:8083/article/june-3-2015-newsletter
Message sites/openoutreach-7-x-1-19.dd/files/styles/medium_large/public/Portulaca grandiflora.jpg
Severity    warning
Hostname    127.0.0.1

There is no medium_large folder in my styles folder. Do I need to create one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was rumaging through the module listing and found Debut Article. On the oft-chance that this might be causing problems I went to the debut article page on drupal.org and found drupal.org/node/1473574. It states that because fields are not true exportables, the resulting approach may be fragile and prone to breakage if, e.g., debut_media is not enabled prior to the article implementing the hook_alter, i.e., in this case, debut_article. I enabled debut media and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

When contrib images are missing in drupal the cause more often than not is that you have permissions problems with regards to your filesystem.

Make sure that your **webserver can write to** your **files and files/styles directories.**

If permissions are ok then drupal will create your medium_large directory and subdirectories.

Check the drupal [setup documentation here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/settings-file) (see the paragraph **"Create the files directory"**).
As mentioned there make sure that you have write permissions on your sites/default/files directory.

Comment: Comments have been removed. Please don't use them for extended discussion.