# Image upload permissions problem

Tags: media

I have my local site running on my Win 7 machine using Acquia Dev Desktop.

I also have a "live" version of the site.

In both environments I cannot upload an image for an article. I must have messed something up because it was working several days ago.

This link https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/image was useful, but the suggestions on Troubleshooting/The image doesn't show up didn't fix the problem. I'm sure it's because I don't really understand what I'm doing.

I'm wondering if a disable of the image module then a re-enable would solve the problem?

Comment: In order to check for a permissions problem, we need to know what your permissions are. Can you check the permissions on both the directory that the Drupal is trying to upload the image to, and add that to your question? It would also help if you can show us the user and group that owns the directory. Disabling and re-enabling the module is unlikely to help, but it probably wouldn't hurt if you wanted to give it a try (on your dev site).

Comment: You probably changed the Onwer/Group name. You should ask Bluehost to help you with this. They have a help chat or e-mail ticketing system. I don't think the problem is Drupal related, it's a folder permission OR Owner/Group thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was rumaging through the module listing and found Debut Article. On the oft-chance that this might be causing problems I went to the debut article page on drupal.org and found drupal.org/node/1473574. It states that because fields are not true exportables, the resulting approach may be fragile and prone to breakage if, e.g., debut_media is not enabled prior to the article implementing the hook_alter, i.e., in this case, debut_article. I enabled debut media and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked **Home » Administration » Configuration » Media**
IN this **Public file system path** should be "sites/default/files" and **Temporary directory** should be "/tmp".
And check whether you files folder has read/write permissions and its subfolder's where you are saving image.

Comment: I checked Public file system path. It was set incorrectly as was the Temporary Directory. I fixed them. If finally found out from bluehost my owner name and how to use cpanel to set permissions. I changed both folders' permissions from 755 to 777. I flushed all caches. My image now appears on the home page, but not the article page. I drilled down further into the folder heirarchy and changed more permissions with no luck.

Comment: Please see my latest attempt to solve this problem at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160761/image-shows-on-home-page-but-not-on-article-page

Comment: I THINK I FOUND THE SOLUTION! I'm crossing my fingers that this is a permanent fix. I was rumaging through the module listing and found Debut Article. On the oft-chance that this might be causing problems I went to the debut article page on drupal.org and found https://www.drupal.org/node/1473574. It states that because fields are not true exportables, the resulting approach may be fragile and prone to breakage if, e.g., debut_media is not enabled prior to the article implementing the hook_alter, i.e., in this case, debut_article. I enabled debut media and it worked!

Comment: Please see related question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160761/image-shows-on-home-page-but-not-on-article-page/160765?noredirect=1#comment194177_160765. Hopefully my solution will help others.